# How to avoid the dreaded Data Table when copying and pasting charts in Libreoffice Calc

Tags: charts, libreoffice-calc, copy, paste

Libreoffice Calc has a curious and frustrating behaviour, in that when copying a chart from one tab to another in a workbook, in the majority of cases the duplicated chart is furnished with a copy of the data from the original source, not a live link to the original data. The result is that if the source data changes, the duplicate chart does not update as expected.

The behaviour appears to be intermittent, where sometimes, the duplicate chart maintains a link to the original data. I am yet to identify any difference in process that leads to this result. How does one reliably copy and paste a chart in Calc without having it create a fixed Data Table.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create chart with link to data
2. Create new tab
3. Copy the existing chart either with Ctrl+C or /Copy
4. Paste chart into new tab with either Ctrl+V or / Paste
5. <right click)/Edit new chart
6. new chart while in edit mode
7. Observe presence (or absence) of 'Data Table' menu item in context menu